# Using Plugin in place of Gem in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want use plugins in place of gems in my Rails application so that I can change the code of a gem which is still under development. Once I remove it from my gemfile and put it as a plugin in the vendor\plugin folder, what else do I need to do to make Rails undesrstand that It needs to use the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nothing. Its done.

```
rails plugin install ********
```

Use this to install your respective plugin. Restart your server and its done.

Answer (score 0):

You're developing a gem, but you want to load it as a plugin?  I'm not sure that's the route you want to take.  If you have a gem to start with, why not vendorize it and put its path in the Gemfile?

Example:

(from the root of your app)

```
gem unpack mygem --target vendor/gems
```

(in Gemfile)

```
gem 'mygem', :path => "vendor/gems/mygem-VERSION"
```